# Displaying username and uid

Tags: text-processing

```
cut -f 1,3 -d ':' --output-delimiter=' ' /etc/passwd
```

Using the code above I get this result

```
root 0
bin 1
daemon 2
adm 3
lp 4
sync 5
shutdown 6
halt 7
mail 8
operator 11
games 12
ftp 14
nobody 99
systemd-network 192
dbus 81
polkitd 999
ntp 38
sshd 74
postfix 89
chrony 998
adilfanta 1000
miked 5001
mca 5002
mdrock 5003
finalexam 5004
mysql 27
apache 48
```

I want to get a result like this below for each line

```
Name mca and uid  5002
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` gives a bit more flexibility for formatting output, beyond the raw extraction of columns that `cut` provides:

```
awk -F : '{ printf "Name %s and uid %d\n", $1, $3 }' /etc/passwd
```

or, with support for systems that may be using a directory service (this would also work on systems where `/etc/passwd` provides the `passwd` database, but not macOS),

```
getent passwd |
awk -F : '{ printf "Name %s and uid %d\n", $1, $3 }'
```

The `awk` code prints out the first and third `:`-delimited column of every line as part of a text string formatted using `printf`.